# python multiprocessing freezing 1

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
from source.RUN import*

    def func(r,grid,pos,h):
    return r,grid,pos,h
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()  # Creates a pool with as many workers as you have CPU cores
    results = []


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in  pos[-1]<2:
    results.append(Pool.apply_async(LISTE,(r,grid,pos[i,:],h)))
    p.close()
    p.join()

 for result in results:
   print('liste', result.get())
```

I want to create Pool for (LISTE,(r,grid,pos[i,:],h)) process and i is in pos which is variable in different file which is a ndarray[] and I have to call this whole function in another file in between one While Loop. but this code gives error and if I am using if **name** == '**main**': it will not pass through below the if **name** == '**main**': module please give me idea how I can make it